# java convert Object to double array

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have a piece of code that returns an Object array. Each slice of the array then contains data that was initially a two dimensional array of doubles. I can't change this piece of code as it's part a  Matlab thing (see link below).

http://www.mathworks.com/help/mps/java/code-multiple-outputs-for-java-client.html

My question is how do I convert each slice of the Object[]  back into a double[][] within Java?

Here's some sample code

```
Object[] test = getDailyLog(1,20050101,20060101);
Object a = test[1];
System.out.println(a);
```

From this I get the output

```
[[D@17b90c55
```

Comment: What is the return type getDailyLog?

Comment: It's unclear from your description what sort of objects are actually in the array.  You need to change your code snippet above to do `System.out.println(a.getClass().getName());`, to show the class of the objects.  Then one can figure out how to extract the values.

Comment: (But the `[[` prefix above suggests you have a two-dimensional array, and *maybe* the `D` means `double` (been a long time since I've looked at the default `toString` for an array).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, it could be inferred that 'test' is an array of "double[][]".
Therefore, you could use the coersion cast to fulfil your requirement, example is listed as below:

```
        Object[] test = getDailyLog(1,20050101,20060101);

        double[][] d2d;
        for(Object obj : test) {
            d2d = (double[][]) obj;
        }
```

Comment: Of course, that would extract all the elements into one array, writing one on top of the next.  You really should extract into a 3-dimensional array.

Comment: More correctly, it would refer to each element using the same reference.

Comment: I changed it so that each Object gets it's own double array variable. Thanks!